# IBM BPM rolling migration to a new OS / hardware

Tags: linux, bpm

Our existing BPM cluster runs on the Red Hat 6 Hosts and need to be upgraded to Red Hat 7.
Here is the BPM configuration:

```
WebSphere Application Server
8.5.5.13

IBM Business Process Manager
8.6.0.201803
```

The Deployment Environment is a IBM BPM Advanced Process Server with Application(x2), Remote Messaging(x2) and Remote Support(x2) clusters.

```
Cell
TST.AppCluster => Nodes 
Node1 (ND 8.5.5.13, BPMServer 8.6.0.201803) 
Node2 (ND 8.5.5.13, BPMServer 8.6.0.201803) 
TST.MECluster => Nodes 
Node1 (ND 8.5.5.13, BPMServer 8.6.0.201803) 
Node2 (ND 8.5.5.13, BPMServer 8.6.0.201803)
TST.SupCluster  => Nodes 
Node1 (ND 8.5.5.13, BPMServer 8.6.0.201803) 
Node2 (ND 8.5.5.13, BPMServer 8.6.0.201803)
```

Is it possible to perform a rolling migration to a new hardware by dynamically adding new nodes/hosts 
into the existing cluster and later removing old rhel 6 machines?
Or there is a better way to migrate to the new OS without downtime?